# Homemade Javascript Chrome Extension not working on pdfs open in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, screenshot

First time poster and amateur programmer who's run into a problem they can't solve, so be gentle...

I have a Javascript Chrome Extension running in Manifest v3 and I've been trying to make a screenshot extension where you first draw an overlay over the desired area on the chrome browser, this is then drawn onto a canvas which is then saved out.

I've slowly worked out the nuances of foreground, background scripts etc, and it works on websites. But it doesn't work on pdfs which are opened in the browser. No errors are thrown, it just doesn't produce an overlay. I really want this to work on pdfs as well for a different application I have in mind for auto uploading parts of a pdf to a google sheet from the chrome extension.

I've tried googling to no avail, but I'm hoping it's something to do with permissions. I've tried messing with the manifest.json to give host permissions, but no joy. Is it even possible to run an extension like this on a pdf open in a chrome browser?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated on how to do this! Ive copied the manifest.json and foreground.js script below:

**foreground.js**

```
var selectionOverlay = document.createElement('div');
selectionOverlay.style.position = 'absolute'; // Set overlay position to absolute
selectionOverlay.style.border = '2px solid red'; // Set border style
selectionOverlay.style.background = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)'; // Set background color with alpha
selectionOverlay.style.pointerEvents = 'none'; // Make overlay ignore mouse events


// Initialize variables for tracking the selection
var selectionStarted = false;
var startX, startY, endX, endY;
var screenshotDataUrl = 0;

// Event handler for the start of the selection
function handleSelectionStart(event) {

  if (selectionStarted) {
  
    // Append the overlay to the body of the document
    document.body.appendChild(selectionOverlay);
    // Set the starting coordinates of the selection
    startX = event.clientX;
    startY = event.clientY;

    // Set initial position of the overlay
    updateOverlayPosition(startX, startY);
  }
}

// Event handler for the movement of the selection
function handleSelectionMove(event) {
  if (selectionStarted) {
    // Update overlay position as the mouse moves
    updateOverlayPosition(event.clientX, event.clientY);
  }
}

// Event handler for the end of the selection
function handleSelectionEnd(event) {
  console.log("Test2");
  if (selectionStarted) {
    // Reset the selection flag
    endX = event.clientX;
    endY = event.clientY;
    selectionStarted = false;
    console.log("Test2.5");
    // Get the selection range and its bounding rectangle
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();
    captureSelectedArea(range);
    // Capture the selected area and send the data to the popup script
    // Remove the overlay after the selection is complete
    removeOverlay();
  }
}

// Update the overlay position based on mouse coordinates
function updateOverlayPosition(x, y) {
  selectionOverlay.style.left = Math.min(startX, x) + 'px';
  selectionOverlay.style.top = Math.min(startY, y) + 'px';
  selectionOverlay.style.width = Math.abs(startX - x) + 'px';
  selectionOverlay.style.height = Math.abs(startY - y) + 'px';
}

// Remove the overlay from the DOM
function removeOverlay() {
  selectionOverlay.parentNode.removeChild(selectionOverlay);
}

// Capture the selected area and send a message to the background script
function captureSelectedArea(range) {
  console.log("Test3");
  console.log(range);
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = screenshotDataUrl;
  img.onload = function () {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = Math.abs(endX-startX);
    canvas.height = Math.abs(endY-startY);
  
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(img, startX-20, startY-20, canvas.width +20, canvas.height+20, 20, 20, canvas.width+5, canvas.height+20);
    
    var resultDataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'downloadImage', dataUrl: resultDataUrl });
  }
  };

// Add event listeners for mouse events
document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleSelectionStart);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleSelectionMove);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', handleSelectionEnd);

// Listen for messages from the background script
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message.action === 'startSelection') {
    selectionStarted = true;
    screenshotDataUrl = message.dataUrl;
    
    console.log("Reached here!");
  }
});
```

**Manifest.json**

```
{ // Comments are allowed even though it's
    // Manifest version 3 is specified for the Chrome extension.
    "manifest_version": 3,

    // Extension name.
    "name": "Chrome Extension v3 Starter",

    // Description of the extension.
    "description": "A minimal example of a chrome extension using manifest v3",

    // Version of the extension.
    "version": "0.0.1",

    // Icons for different sizes.
    "icons": {
        "16": "logo/logo-16.png",
        "48": "logo/logo-48.png",
        "128": "logo/logo-128.png"
    },

    // Options page for settings.
    "options_page": "settings/settings.html",

    // Action details for the extension.
    "action": {
        "default_title": "Chrome Addon v3 Starter",
        "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
    },

    // Permissions required by the extension.
    "permissions": ["activeTab","downloads","storage","tabs"],

    // Host permissions for the extension, allowing access to all URLs.
    "host_permissions": [
        "*://*/*",
        "file://*/*.pdf"
    ],

    // Background service worker for handling background tasks.
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "service-worker.js"
    },

    // Content scripts to be injected into specific matches (e.g., GitHub pages).
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": ["foreground.js"],
        "matches": ["<all_urls>", "file://*/*.pdf","*://*/*.pdf"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }]
}
```

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to run an extension in the PDF viewer of Chrome, but I could be wrong. It's been a while since I last checked/tested this.

Comment: If you're looking at a tab with a PDF file, there's barely a DOM; the window is filled with an `<embed>` for the PDF viewer.